# Bad rendering of the local index.html from public folder using HUGO

Tags: html, css, hugo, base-url, blogdown

I am creating a web using RStudio and HUGO, by means of the `Blogdown` package.

When serving the site locally in RStudio, it seems to be rendered properly. All the files are created within the folder `/public`.

[image]

However, when I open the file `index.html` from the `/public` folder, I get this appearance.

[image]

I am employing the theme `Mainroad` with this base URL:

`baseurl = "/"`

Any idea why when opening the HTML file it is not rendered properly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks [to the HUGO forum](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/bad-rendering-of-the-local-index-html-from-public-folder-using-hugo/17370), I post the answer that worked for me, just in case somebody get here.

It is pretty simple, just by adding two lines at the top of the `config.toml` file:

```
relativeURLs = true
uglyURLs = true
```

Comment: Hi all, I acually added these 2 lines of code. but still the same page (2nd Image of the question)

Comment: It is probably because the css is not loaded correctly, check that the link to the css files are starting with `https:`

Answer (score 1):

Open the html file in a text editor and check the exact links given for the stylesheets. More than likely, it is not resolvable by the web-browser because it starts with a `/` and so looks like an absolute path.

When viewed via the microserver packaged with hugo, that would be seen as relative to the server. But when view via a file url, it is seen as an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Blogdown has released an updated version on CRAN that may address this issue.  See this link for discussion: https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/372